# Magento2 - Form validate instant and add class

Tags: magento2.3, form-validation, validate

Is there a way to directly validate a form in `Magento2.3x`?

So that when the input focus goes to the next input element, it automatically validates the previous input and add a class to the input?

We want to show some approve or decline icon when a user fills the form in correct.
This so the customer knows the input is or is not correct.

It's quite easy `JS` on `Magento1.9x`, but I can not find it for `Magento2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different ways to use form validation in magento 2

To enable javascript validation use following code in your template

```
<form class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
 <fieldset class="fieldset">
     <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Personal Information') ?></span></legend><br>
      <div class="field required">
          <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
          <div class="control">
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
          </div>
      </div>
 </fieldset>
 <div class="actions-toolbar">
      <div class="primary">
          <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php  echo __('Submit') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span></button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

1

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

2

```
<form data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

   var dataForm = $('#custom-form');
   dataForm.mage('validation', {});

});
</script>
```

*custom-form is form id you can replace it with your form id

**List of form validation rules**

To wrap up this article, a list of validation rule names is provided here as a quick reference toward the official documentation:

**Magento rules:**

```
validate-no-html-tags

validate-select

validate-no-empty

validate-alphanum-with-spaces

validate-data

validate-street

validate-phoneStrict

validate-phoneLax

validate-fax

validate-email

validate-emailSender

validate-password

validate-admin-password

validate-customer-password

validate-url

validate-clean-url

validate-xml-identifier

validate-ssn

validate-zip-us

validate-date-au

validate-currency-dollar

validate-not-negative-number

validate-zero-or-greater

validate-greater-than-zero

validate-css-length

validate-number

required-number

validate-number-range

validate-digits

validate-digits-range

validate-range

validate-alpha

validate-code

validate-alphanum

validate-date

validate-date-range

validate-cpassword

validate-identifier

validate-zip-international

validate-one-required

validate-state

required-file

validate-ajax-error

validate-optional-datetime

validate-required-datetime

validate-one-required-by-name

less-than-equals-to

greater-than-equals-to

validate-emails

validate-cc-type-select

validate-cc-number

validate-cc-type

validate-cc-exp

validate-cc-cvn

validate-cc-ukss

validate-length

required-entry

not-negative-amount

validate-per-page-value-list

validate-per-page-value

validate-new-password

required-if-not-specified

required-if-all-sku-empty-and-file-not-loaded

required-if-specified

required-number-if-specified

datetime-validation

required-text-swatch-entry

required-visual-swatch-entry

required-dropdown-attribute-entry

Validate-item-quantity

validate-grouped-qty

validate-one-checkbox-required-by-name

validate-date-between

validate-dob

max-words

min-words

range-words

letters-with-basic-punc

alphanumeric

letters-only

no-whitespace

zip-range

integer

vinUS

dateITA

dateNL

time

time12h

phoneUS

phoneUK

mobileUK

stripped-min-length

email2

url2

credit-card-types

ipv4

ipv6

pattern

allow-container-className
```

**jQuery rules:**

```
required,

remote,

email,

url,

date,

dateISO,

number,

digits,

creditcard,

equalTo,

maxlength,

minlength,

rangelength,

range,

max,

min
```

refer http://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/

If this solution work then please accept it.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does validate the form, but it currently does validate the form already, buy only when pressing the submit button. I want to change this to a instant validation. Without pressing the submit button. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old topic, but maybe someone in the future will look for the same.
You can use attach validation to the input and validate just this field, that you already edited. It would be something like this:

```
input.on('change keyup keydown keypress click blur', function () {
    let value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length) {
        $(this).validation();
    }
}
```

You can also validate a complete form with changing line no. 4 into

`$('#id-of-your-form').validation()`

But please remember that you need to have validation widget attached to the form `mage-init` as described before.